# Gerbes over finite fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, stacks, gerbes

Let $k$ be a field with algebraic closure $\bar{k}$.

Recall that a *gerbe* over $k$ is an algebraic stack $\mathcal{G}$ over $k$ such that the groupoid $\mathcal{G}(\bar{k})$ is connected. We say that $\mathcal{G}$ is *neutral* if $\mathcal{G}(k)$ is non-empty.

Now assume that $k = \mathbb{F}_q$ is a finite field.

> Is any gerbe over $\mathbb{F}_q$ neutral?

Gerbes are classified by 2nd Galois cohomology, and $\mathbb{F}_q$ has cohomological dimension $1$ which is why I suspect this is the case. But there are a lot of subtleties to the theory, e.g. abelian vs non-abelian gerbes or banded vs non-banded gerbes. So there could be some technicalities I'm over looking (perhaps even my take on the definition of a gerbe is too naive?)

Comment: Neat question! I would just fix the typo, but I kind of enjoy the idea of a theory with subtitles.

Comment: Gerbes: The Final Frontier

Comment: It might help to have the correct definition of a gerbe: A stack is a gerbe if (a) each $G_{S}$ is a groupoid (all morphisms are isomorphisms); (b) there exists an 
$S\neq\emptyset$ such that $G_{S}\neq\emptyset$; and (c) any two objects of $G_{S}$ are locally isomorphic.

Comment: If you assume that there exists an $x$ in $G(\bar{k})$, where $\bar{k}$ is the algebraic closure of $k$, and $Aut(x)$ is an algebraic group, then it follows from Theorem 3.5 of Springer 1966 that $G(k)$ is nonempty. (Nonabelian $H^2$ in Galois cohomology, Springer, T. A., Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, R.I., 1966, pp 164-182.)

Comment: Your definition looks incomplete, objects should exist locally, that is $\mathcal{G}(\bar{k})$ should be non empty.

Comment: The definition is Giraud's original definition.

Comment: @anon I know your definition is correct, my comment was about the definition given by Daniel Loughran

Comment: @anon: Modulo the missing assumption that $\mathcal{G}(\bar{k})$ is non-empty, how does my definition differ from yours? Are there algebraic stacks which satisfy one definition but not the other? Just your condition (b) seems to hold automatically as $\mathcal{G}$ was assumed to be an algebraic stack, and your condition (c) feels very similar to my condition that $\mathcal{G}(\bar{k})$ is connected (by which I naturally mean that any two $\bar{k}$-points are isomorphic). It feels like a descent argument should reduce one definition to the other.

Comment: @anon: In any case I think multiple answers are welcome on MO and I would be very happy for you to upgrade your comment to an answer.

Comment: @DanielLoughran When I read the question, I assumed that a connected groupoid was required to be non-empty, like a connected topological space or a connected graph, for the same reason that 1 is not a prime number. So non-emptiness of $\mathcal{G}(\overline{k})$ is not missing (but maybe Niels uses a different definition of connectedness of groupoids).

Comment: Yes I had also thought that but didnt want to come across as a smart arse :) In any case the important condition is anon's condition (c) and how it relates to my definition.

Comment: In case the gerbe has affine diagonal this is Theorem 8.1 in Di Proietto, Tonini and Zhang,  Frobenius fixed objects of moduli. Actually, they show this for general fpqc gerbes, without finiteness hypotheses.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suppose that $x$ is an object of $\mathcal{G}$ over a finite extension $k'/k$. Denote $\sigma : k' \to k'$ the $q$-power frobenius. Let $x^\sigma$ be the pullback of of $x$ by $\sigma$. As $\mathcal{G}$ is a gerbe over $k$, after replacing $k'$ by a further finite extension, we may assume there is an isomorphism $\alpha : x^\sigma \to x$ over $k'$. If $n = [k' : k]$, then consider the automorphism $\beta = \alpha \circ \alpha^\sigma \circ \dotsb \circ \alpha^{\sigma^{n - 1}}$ of $x$ over $k'$. If $\beta = \operatorname{id}$, then $\alpha$ determines a descent datum and since $\mathcal{G}$ is a stack, we would be able to descend $x$ to an object over $k$ and the gerbe would be neutral.

OK, but perhaps $\beta$ is not trivial. However, then $\beta$ is an element of the automorphism group of $x$ over $k'$ which is (if we have a suitable finiteness assumption on $\mathcal{G}$, for example if $\mathcal{G}$ is quasi-separated — an assumption that always holds in practice) the $k'$-points of an algebraic group over $k'$. Thus $\beta$ has finite order as $k'$ is a finite field. Say $\beta$ has order $m \geq 1$. Then after replacing $k'$ by an extension of degree $m$, and going trough the whole process again, we end up with $\beta = \operatorname{id}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ is neutral.

Comment: There are people (strange people) who assume almost no separatedness hypotheses of their stacks.

Comment: This is a nice argument!

Comment: I quite like how explicit this argument is and avoids a discussion of non-abelian cohomology. Thanks! I would still be very happy to see other answers which present an alternative viewpoint on using cohomology to address this problem.

Comment: If the gerbe is étale, then the fact that the cohomological dimension of the Galois group is 1 does imply that it is neutralizable (see for example the proof of Lemma 4.4) in my paper with Giulio Bresciani "Fields of moduli and the arithmetic of tame quotient singularities". In the general case I am not sure how to proceed.